# How to skip iOS 9.3 update?

Tags: ios, software-update

Is there a way to skip this (or any future) updates?  I'm using an iPhone 5s.

Comment: Yes, just do not update the software, when you will eventually asked to :)

Comment: yeah but everyday it asks me to do it and the only choices are install now or remind me later.  I'd like to not be bothered by this everyday

Comment: Given recent events we've all read about in the news, this seems like an amazingly bad idea.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, perhaps you could provide a link for those who lack the context that seems so obvious to you?

Comment: @Wildcard To begin with, [the obvious](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2016/03/apple-fight-about-all-us). Then the [less obvious](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2016/03/imessage_encryp.html), and finally the [totally non-obvious but still critically important](http://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2016/03/acedeceiver-first-ios-trojan-exploiting-apple-drm-design-flaws-to-infect-any-ios-device/). Not installing security updates is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1: Delete the update from your iOS device.**

- Go to Settings from your Home screen
- Select Storage and iCloud Usage
- Go to "Manage Storage"
- Find the iOS update that is bothering you and select it
- Tap on "Delete Update" and confirm

However, you'll have to stay off of Wi-fi, otherwise it'll re-download.

**Option 2: Block Software Update domains on your router / gateway**

You'll have to figure this one out on your own, since all routers are different, but the domains you'll want to block are:

- `appldnld.apple.com`
- `mesu.apple.com`

**Option 3: Just update**

You can also give in and submit to the installation. This will bring you up to the latest, most reliable and up-to-date version of iOS, but if you don't want to, that's definitely fine.